# "Such being..."

Tags: phrase-meaning, syntactic-analysis

I read in Ivanhoe by Walter Scott the following:

> Such being our chief scene, the date of our story refers to a period towards the end of the reign of Richard I.,...

I'm curious about the construction at the beginning of the sentence: *Such being our chief scene...*. I have a general understanding, but how should I parse it? What is the tense? Is it a kind of adverbial clause? How could this be restated?

Answer (score 2):

It helps to have some context from the preceding paragraph. Below, I have reproduced its last two sentences:

> The remains of this extensive wood are still to be seen at the noble seats of Wentworth, of Warncliffe Park, and around Rotherham. Here haunted of yore the fabulous Dragon of Wantley; here were fought many of the most desperate battles during the Civil Wars of the Roses; and here also flourished in ancient times those bands of gallant outlaws, whose deeds have been rendered so popular in English song.

"Such being our chief scene, ..." could be rewritten "This being the main setting, ..."

This is a parenthetical adverbial clause located, like the main clause, in the writer's present.

Answer (score 0):

This is an *absolute* (unattached) clause, a type of subordinate clause which has that Latinate name because it not bound to a particular constituent of its head clause but modifies the entire head clause.

For its verb it employs a present participle, a tenseless form whose temporal reference is inferred from the tense of the head clause—in effect, it ‘borrows’ its tense from the head clause. It is distinguishable from an ordinary participle clause in having its own explicit subject; a participle clause has no explicit subject but, again, ‘borrows’ its subject from the head clause, and is thus ‘bound’ to the subject of the main clause.

The clause inverts the subject and the predicate complement. The complement *such* is a pronoun referring to the preceding description, which Erik Kowal has reproduced for us.

If recast as an independent clause, the clause would read like this:

> Our chief scene is such. The date of our story refers ....

Usually there is a clear causal or consequential connection between the absolute clause and its head, the absolute clause describing an eventuality which gives rise to or explains the eventuality described in the main clause. [That last sentence, in fact, exemplifies the principle.] Your example is remarkable for the unusual looseness of the connection: Scott leaves it to the reader to infer that what he means is, approximately, “Now that I have defined the scene I may proceed to defining the date.”